Are reimplementations of algorithms still subject to licensing of the original software?
E.g. Google provides the source code for Material Design 3 dynamic color algorithm licensed under Apache license. Can the theming algorithms be reimplemented by just reusing values (and not the actual source code, that will be original) and then licensed with a different license?

It depends on whether the algorithm is patented. Copyright protects source code, patents protect methods.

The Apache license allows almost all kinds of reusing the code, so why would you want to rewrite it?

A UI also has the potential for protection with a design patent, also called registered design. Certain elements may also be trademarked.

Isn't this akin to how Compaq created its version of the BIOS via clean-room actions?  They had one team look at the  code that produced the "values" of the BIOS, then had a different team write code that produced the same "values".

this would relate to patents methinks.  Sometimes an algorithm is patented but it's for a specific purpose.  Ex:  Google's pagerank algorithm (they actually licensed it from a university methinks... that particular patent has expired.)

@PMF for self education or entertainment, perhaps.
